# Is there any significant delay in initializing AudioTrack on Android?

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to pass through the audio samples obtained at the MIC to the speaker using AudioRecord and AudioTrack. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 44100;
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1024;  // 1024 ORIGINAL
    final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    int i= 0;
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private volatile boolean passThroughMode = true;
        // /*
        MyThread(){
            super();
        }

        MyThread(boolean newPTV){
            this.passThroughMode = newPTV;
        }
        // */

        // /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            int num = 0;
            // am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); // -> MOVED THESE TO init()
            // am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            while (passThroughMode) {
            // while (!isInterrupted()) {
                num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                    lin[i] *= WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR; 
                track.write(lin, 0, num);
            }
            // /*
            record.stop();
            track.stop();
            record.release();
            track.release();
            // */
        }
        // */

        // /*
        public void stopThread(){
            passThroughMode = false;
        }
        // */
    }

    MyThread newThread;

    private void init() {
        int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                                 AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
        int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                               AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        // init(); // -> Moved this to onResume();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onCreate() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        // newThread.stopThread();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onResume() called");
        init();
        newThread = new MyThread(true);
        newThread.start(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("MYLOG", "onPause() called");
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void passStop(View view){
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);  
        // /*
        if(!isPlaying){
            record.startRecording();
            track.play();
            isPlaying = true;
            playBtn.setText("Pause");
        }
        else{
           record.stop();
           track.pause();
           isPlaying=false;
           playBtn.setText("Pass through");
        }
        // */
    }

    // /*
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        newThread.stopThread();
        // android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        // newThread.interrupt();
         Log.d("MYLOG", "onDestroy() called");
    }
    // */
}
```

The program is supposed to start a Thread that performs a pass through. The Thread starts at the app's onResume() so should start immediately. But there is always a 1.5~2 sec delay at the beginning. I assumed that it might be because of onCreate() and other initialization happening before the Thread starts in onResume(), but if I print out the contents of the `lin` array to file, it always writes a long line of 0's at the beginning which indicates the delay is probably not due tot he time required for initializing. So what is this delay seen here? Does track.play() need a significant time to start playing?

Comment: user13267, did you ever discover the answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

I am debugging a similar delay, and while I don't have the complete answer yet, it appears that the AudioManager is introducing the delay in the setMode call (am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)).